# Storing adjacency matrix as graph object in Python

Tags: python, networkx

I have network data with adjacency square matrix and no keys included (no identifier for the person included).

How do I store my adjacency matrix (csv file) as a graph object with networkx package?

Answer (score 0):

To store your matrix as the csv format, I think you should convert it into the `pandas` DataFrame first. To do that, you can refer to this https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_pandas_adjacency.html#networkx.convert_matrix.to_pandas_adjacency
. Note that you might need to use `index` or `columns` attribute to custom your indexes if you want to a name for each node under the format of DataFrame.

After converting the graph into `pandas` DataFrame, you can use `to_csv` to export it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get your adjacency matrix from csv format into a graph object, but the most straightforward, in my opinion, is to load the adjacency matrix using pandas, and then directly create a graph from the pandas dataframe object:

```
# Example 3x3 adjacency matrix in csv file:

# 0  1  0
# 1  0  1
# 0  1  0

import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

adjmat_df = pd.read_csv('adjmat.csv',header=None)

# This gives us the following dataframe:
#    0  1  2
# 0  0  1  0
# 1  1  0  1
# 2  0  1  0

# Create networkx graph object
G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(adjmat_df)

print(nx.info(G))
# Name: 
# Type: Graph
# Number of nodes: 3
# Number of edges: 2
# Average degree:   1.3333

nx.draw_shell(G, with_labels=True, alpha=0.7, font_size=15, node_size=500, node_color='r')
```

[image: graph]

And if you have node labels that you want to use, you can just set the columns and index of the pandas dataframe to be the list of node labels:

```
node_labels = ['A','B','C']
adjmat_df.columns = node_labels
adjmat_df.index = node_labels

G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(adjmat_df)
nx.draw_shell(G, with_labels=True, alpha=0.7, font_size=15, node_size=500, node_color='r')
```

[image: graph_with_node_labels (]